# What's a reliable way to browser sniff Safari on Mac OS X 10.9+ (where "Power Saver" may be enabled)?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, osx-mavericks

Due to the "Power Saver" feature introduced for the Safari browser on Mac OS X Mavericks, I would like to sniff a browser's user agent to detect when it is running Safari on Mac OS X 10.9+ so that I can fall back to an HTML5 video player instead of a Flash one.

After some research:

User Agent on my PowerBook Pro running Safari/Mac OS X 10.8:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.1 Safari/536.26.14"

User Agent on another PowerBook Pro running Safari/Mac OS X 10.9:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14"

My primary concern is that the user agent may be different on a different type of Mac such as a Mac Pro. Can someone verify that the following solution will work across all Safari browsers on Mac OS X 10.9+ regardless of device?

```
function mayHavePowerSaverEnabled() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent,
        versionData;
    return ua.match(/\bSafari\b/) && ua.match(/\bMacintosh\b/) && (versionData = ua.match(/\bMac OS X (\d+)_(\d+)/)) && parseInt(versionData[2]) >= 9;
}
```